# Can a pregnant woman enter a cemetery?

Tags: women, pregnancy-birth, cemetery-grave

I heard that a pregnant woman should not enter a cemetery. I understand this is a minhag and not halacha but would be interested to understand more about this topic.

- What is the source of that minhag?
- Any particular justification for
  it?
- Is it universally accepted and practiced?
- Does it also apply to a woman not going to a funeral for one of the seven close people for which she sits *shiva*?

Comment: Igeres Hagra says no woman should enter a cemetery, as I recall.

Comment: There's extensive discussion in Halakhic sources about pregnant wives of Kohanim entering a cemetery (in case the kid is male). The implication is that generally it is not a problem Halakhically.

Comment: I believe that a fetus does not have human status until born https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/the-fetus-in-jewish-law/ so it would seem to make sense that a Cemetery would not contaminate the unborn male. Chabad https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2515643/jewish/Pregnant-and-Visiting-Cemetery.htm identifies this practice as a custom women took upon themselves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:u7-OoP54z0AJ:https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2515643/jewish/Pregnant-and-Visiting-Cemetery.htm%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) is one of, what I'd surmise, many sources:

> there is no written source in Jewish law that expressly forbids it.
>   This is an interesting example of a tradition that When you are
>   creating life, it is better to avoid contact with death women took
>   upon themselves without being told. And this tradition is carefully
>   guarded and well known, even more than some outright laws. You will
>   see why.
>
> Jewish mothers have known for thousands of years what modern research
>   is only recently discovering. The unborn child is affected by the
>   spiritual and emotional state of the mother. Her moods, her attitudes,
>   and her surroundings are imprinted on the body and soul of the child.
>
> This is why the cemetery is not the right place for a pregnant woman.
>   When you are creating life, it is better to avoid contact with death.
>   The morbid and deathly energy of a cemetery is starkly in contrast to
>   the process taking place inside a pregnant woman. Her focus should
>   remain on the beginning of life, not the end.
>
> Furthermore, feelings of excessive grief or distress may disturb the
>   otherwise peaceful time in the womb. Sometimes emotional pain is
>   unavoidable in life, but we don't have to seek it out. An expecting
>   mother may be fragile and delicate at the best of times. Attending a
>   funeral or consecration may cause an exaggerated reaction that could
>   have been avoided.